# How to remove old ethernet adapter (not showing the network center)?

Tags: windows

I had an old network adapter and it was the Ethernet in network center. Now I changed the adapter, and the new one is called Ethernet(2). And if I try to change to Ethernet, it will say the device already existed. I have removed this before but I haven't used Windows for a while now so I forgot. I remember it was in a file of which I can open up with a text editor and remove the old entries.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

1. Press Windows key + X and go to device manager. Select View tab and choose "Show hidden devices".

Navigate to network adapters and delete only the greyed out ones (inactive)

Using registry:

1. Press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> keys and type `regedit`.
2. Navigate to

```
 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Nla\Cache\Intranet
```

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles
```

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Signatures\Unmanaged
```

- Dig through all of the keys, subkeys, and values under each of those keys, and look for any instances of "`Network`" and "`Network 2`" in the values. Delete any keys (i.e., the whole key "folder") that contain values set to "`Network`".

  These are the registry entries for your old network, which is no longer in use.
- Find all of the keys that contain values set to "`Network 2`", and rename those values to "`Network`". These are the registry entries for your new network.
- Reboot your computer.